# Ошибка в VS: "There can be at most 2-non -write back partitions per measure group in standard edition"

Tags: visual-studio, partition

Есть куб с тремя партициями.
Добавил еще две, стал выбивать следующую ошибку:

> There can be at most 2-non -write back partitions per measure group in
>   standard edition

Просьба помочь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Дополнительные сведения и, по сути, ответ на мой вопрос.
После создания партиций и последующего процеcсинга любой из них, VS выбивает еще одну ошибку с указанием ограничения на создание больше 3-х партиций к одной мере в кубе в Standart Edition.
Если есть что добавить, you are welcome.